# how to grab a data from existing field in Django

Tags: django

I have a web page that I have to connect with Django. So I have an existing form with input and submit button. I have created a model and form. I put {{form}} tag and a little unstyled form appeared. but I want to grab a data from the one in HTML file. The code:

form file:

```
class NumberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Number
        fields = "__all__"
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<div class="line>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber2" value="" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__">
<button class="button_blue">t</button>
</div>
<label class="container_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: add name attribute to your input tag

Comment: @marmeladze ok but where to use it